# JS: 'this' collision in unit test for publication?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, this, chai

I'm doing a unit test for publications of my meteor application. I need to change the timeout intervall, so I added `this.timeout(5000)`. But this gives me the error

```
Error: this.error is not a function
at [object Object]._onTimeout
```

which comes from `if (!this.userId) { return this.error() }` of my publication file.

How can this be fixed?

As you can see, if the user is not logged in, the publication should throw an error. I want to test for this expected error.

**test.js**

```
import { expect } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai'
import { PublicationCollector } from 'meteor/johanbrook:publication-collector'

describe('Publication', () => {
  it('should not return data', function (done) {
    this.timeout(5000)
    const collector = new PublicationCollector()
    collector.collect('list', (collections) => {
      expect(collections.collection).to.be.undefined
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

**server/publication.js**

```
Meteor.publish('list', function (id) {
  if (!this.userId) { return this.error() }
  return Collection.find({})
})
```

Comment: Where is the `error` function defined?

Comment: It is a meteor function: http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you see the timeout because this.userId isn't defined, so publish never returns.

In order to test your publish function, I think you need to:

1) create a user

2) stub i.e. replace the Meteor.user() function which returns the current logged in user in methods

3) provide that user's _id to PublicationsCollector, which will send it in to your publish function.

Here's how I did it:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Factory } from 'meteor/dburles:factory';
import { PublicationCollector } from 'meteor/johanbrook:publication-collector';
import { resetDatabase } from 'meteor/xolvio:cleaner';
import faker from 'faker';
import { Random } from 'meteor/random';
import { chai, assert } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
// and also import your publish and collection

Factory.define('user', Meteor.users, {
    'name': 'Josephine',
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    describe('Menus', () => {
        beforeEach(function () {
            resetDatabase();

            const currentUser = Factory.create('user');
            sinon.stub(Meteor, 'user');
            Meteor.user.returns(currentUser); // now Meteor.user() will return the user we just created

            // and create a Menu object in the Menus collection
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            Meteor.user.restore();
            resetDatabase();
        });

        describe('publish', () => {
            it('can view menus', (done) => {
                const collector = new PublicationCollector({ 'userId': Meteor.user()._id }); // give publish a value for this.userId
                collector.collect(
                    'menus',
                    (collections) => {
                        assert.equal(collections.menus.length, 1);
                        done();
                    },
                );
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I've left out the creation of the objects to be published because it seems like you have that working already.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest version of `johanbrook:publication-collector`.

According to its source code the `1.0.10` version *has* `error()` method: https://github.com/johanbrook/meteor-publication-collector/blob/v1.0.10/publication-collector.js#L187